# Spring boot with H2 and Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

Were are building a spring boot application with liquibase and hibernate.
But now we're facing some issues.

It was working for H2, but when switching to oracle wee needed to add the nationalized annotation

```
@Nationalized
public String getCreatedBy() {
```

But now schema validation with h2 is breaking with:

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [created_by] in table [foo]; found [varchar (Types#VARCHAR)], but expecting [nvarchar(255) (Types#NVARCHAR)]
```

What would be the proper way to solve this issue? is there something like a mapping table for oracle and h2?

Comment: maybe to try run h2 in oracle mode?  
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;Mode=Oracle

Comment: and which version of h2 do you use? Just tested on my project with hibernate, spring boot and h2 version 1.4.196. And @Nationalized works fine for me.

Comment: Im running in oracle Mode, zwingend spring boot 2.0.1. will probier exact Versions later

Comment: I suppose you have the property spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
 in your application.properties? I reproduced your problem. If the value of this property "none" - it works. If "validate" - the error occurs. I think you have two ways to solve your problem. First way - change this prop to "none" or "update". Second way - have 2 different application.properties files or spring profiles for h2 and oracle

Comment: Here is a good docs how to parametrise your app properties https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved with

```
 @Column(name = "created_by", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(255)")
```

Comment: What if I don't have access to this entity defition (ie. it's an external dependency)?